# mail directory of exim and courier and ftp accounts?

Tags: exim, dovecot, ftp, centos5

i'm making a server migration from a cpanel centos 5 box to a plain centos box.

i already migrated, files, ssl, user system permissions and installed the basic service:
as proftpd, apache, dovecot, exim, dns etc..

now what i can't find is where are the email accounts and the ftp account (that ones of username@domain.com)

in terms of email i want to migrate the accounts AND the emails stored in the server at the moment.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Look in your exim.conf for the section "local_delivery" - inside here determines how you're delivering mail (mbox, maildir, etc.). Since you're using Dovecot there is most likely a line like so:

```
directory = ${home}/Maildir
```

...however your installation might be different. Then look in dovecot.conf for a similar line named "mail_location", it should look like the Exim one:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

That's going to tell you where all your email is for all your users. Exactly where it's at completely depends on how your particular server is configured (could be real users, virtual users, maildir, mbox, etc.).

Comment: i just found that is not using dovecot, is using courier, the places are the same?

Comment: it's been a long time since I've used courier, but I think it's a compiled-in default to use $HOME/Maildir for each user and you can't change it via a runtime config file. Most likely all the user mail is in their home directories.

Comment: Long time here as well, and I didn't set it up so I don't know the full configuration for this, but for our virtual users we used to have a crazy system of folders and dotfiles that controlled courier.  Virtual hosts (example is user@example.com) were configured in /etc/courier/aliases/example.com (contained `@example.com: example`), then users were configured in /etc/courier/aliasdir/.courier-example-user (contained `/var/mail/virtual/example/user/Mail`)  If you have an /etc/courier/aliasdir, do an ls -al there.